# Error in serving JSON response with Node.js, MongoDB, and express after 1st response

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to make simple restful API's with Node.js express and MongoDB. I am using the Node.js-MongoDB driver along with express framework

```js
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient
const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/"
const dbName = "PractiseDB"
const client = new MongoClient(url, {useNewUrlParser:true})
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000

const express = require('express');
const app = express()

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  client.connect((err) => {
    if (err) throw err
    const collRef =  client.db(dbName).collection('newCollection')
    console.log("Connected ... ")
    collRef.find({}).toArray((err, result) => {
      res.set('Content-Type', 'text/json')
      res.send(result)
      client.close(() => {
        console.log("DB Close...")
      })
    })
  })
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App running on port ${port}`)
})
```

When I run the above snippet, on the first response I get my JSON data but after 1st response I get this on the console,

> the options [servers] is not supported the options [caseTranslate] is
>   not supported

What am I missing or is there some other way to serve JSON?

Comment: Are you using the options servers or caseTranslate, anywhere in your code?

Comment: nope. The code is above which I am using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You close the mongo client after the first request.
That is why you got the error.

To solve it.
Option 1: 
You can move the code that creates a new mongo client inside the route '/'.

Option 2: 
Do not close the mongo client inside the route '/'. Keep the mongo client connection alive, until you shutdown the server.

Comment: According to you what should be the best practice ? Should I make the client inside every route and then close it or keep it open until the server is running ?

Comment: @EhteshamSiddiqui Option 2 should be the best practice. Creating a new mongo connection takes time and resources. Keep it open is more efficient.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate your help!